# Dozer : Number to Number mapping is not supported

Tags: java, integer, dozer

Why dozer can not map Source Class variable of Number type to Destination Class variable of the same type?

Getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Some more Info:
Dest parent class: XXX
Source field name: totalAccounts
Source field type: class java.lang.Integer
Source field value: 8
Dest parent class: XXX
Dest field name: totalAccounts
Dest field type: java.lang.Number
```

Here,both the source and destination classes refer to same Class type say Transactions.Both have Number field but while mapping from source to destination class it is throwing such exception..

I dont understand why should it be "argument mismatch" with same data type?

Answer (score 1):

According to your Dozer message, it is not the same type. The source field is `Integer`, the destination is `Number`.

[The Dozer documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/simpleproperty.html) does not mention such a build-in converter (at least, if I read correctly), so you might need to implement your own implementation of `org.dozer.CustomConverter`.
Since you say it is the same class and the same field, I'm at a loss however why one is `Integer` and the other is `Number` (at least, without more information about the class and your mapping file). Better double-check both the class and the mapping file, and try the `CustomConverter` as a workaround.